# Cell shows on top of section header

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` with custom cells and custom headers. When I move one cell upon editing, it pops up on to of the header view. 
How can I keep the header view on top of all the cells?

The app uses storyboard, in case that makes a difference.

This is how it looks? https://www.dropbox.com/s/wg8oiar0d9oytux/iOS%20SimulatorScreenSnapz003.mov

This is my code:

```
[...]
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListCell";
    ListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    int handleSection = [self sectionToHandle:indexPath.section];

    switch (handleSection)
    {
        case PrivateLists:
        {
            if (tableView.isEditing && (indexPath.row == self.privateLists.count))
            {
                cell.textField.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Lägg till ny lista", nil);
                cell.textField.enabled = NO;
                cell.textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                cell.editingAccessoryView.hidden = YES;
            }
            else
            {
                List *list = [self.privateLists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                cell.textField.text = list.name;
                cell.textField.enabled = YES;
                cell.textField.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

                cell.onTextEntered = ^(NSString* enteredString){
                    list.name = enteredString;
                    UpdateListService *service = [[UpdateListService alloc]initServiceWithList:list];
                    [service updatelistOnCompletion:
                     ^(BOOL success){
                         DLog(@"Updated list");

                         NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:indexPath.section];
                         [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:newPath];

                         [self moveListToTop:list.ListId newIndexPath:newPath];
                         justMovedWithoutSectionUpdate = YES;
                     }
                                                    onError:
                     ^(NSError *error){
                         [[ActivityIndicator sharedInstance] hide];
                         [[ErrorHandler sharedInstance]handleError:error fromSender:self];
                     }];
                };
            }
        }
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 22)];

    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 21)];
    [textLabel setFont:[[AXThemeManager sharedTheme]headerFontWithSize:15.0]];
    [textLabel setTextColor:[[AXThemeManager sharedTheme]highlightColor]];
    [textLabel setText:@"SECTION TITLE"];
    [textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[AXThemeManager sharedTheme].tableviewSectionHeaderBackgroundImage];
    [backgroundView setFrame:view.frame];
    [view addSubview:backgroundView];
    [view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];
    [view addSubview:textLabel];

    return view;
}

- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 22;
}

- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44;
}
[...]
```

Comment: How so? The header is a view of its own, not a UITableViewCell counted as section content. If I put it into the first cell, I scroll it away upon scrolling.

Comment: forget my last comment...will this happen if the cell is a normal one without a textfield no it?

Comment: Yes. I have had such a case as well in an other tableview. There I solved it badly using a loader and "locking" the table while preforming a reloadData. However, that is a bad solution and only a temporary workaround. Hence, this problem is not just a "specific case in time"... its easily recreatable.

Comment: before any smart people have a concrete strong answer, i can only suggest make sure updatelist won't block UI update, or perform reloadData/moveRowAtIndexPath on mainThread... sorry...

Comment: I understand, but thats not it unfortunately. The update ect. is a another thread that just updates the API side with the new data.. nothing more released to the UITableView. It seems to me like an iOS bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good news! I was able to fix/workaround your problem in two different ways (see below).

I would say this is certainly an OS bug.  What you are doing causes the cell you have moved (using `moveRowAtIndexPath:`) to be placed above (in front of) the header cell in the z-order.

I was able to repro the problem in OS 5 and 6, with cells that did and didn't have UITextFields, and with the tableView in and out of edit mode (in your video it is in edit mode, I noticed). It also happens even if you are using standard section headers.

**Paul**, you say in one of your comments:

> I solved it badly using a loader and "locking" the table while
>   preforming a reloadData

I am not sure what you mean by "using a loader and locking the table", but I did determine that calling `reloadData` after `moveRowAtIndexPath:` does fix the problem.  Is that not something you want to do?

```
[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:newPath];
//[self.tableView reloadData];
// per reply by Umka, below, reloadSections works and is lighter than reloadData:
[self reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

If you dont want to do that, here is another solution that feels a little hacky to me, but seems to work well (iOS 5+):

```
__weak UITableViewCell* blockCell = cell;  // so we can refer to cell in the block below without a retain loop warning.
...
cell.onTextEntered = ^(NSString* sText)
{
    // move item in my model
    NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:indexPath.section];
    [self.itemNames removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.itemNames insertObject:sText atIndex:0];

    // Then you can move cell to back
    [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:newPath];
    [self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:blockCell];  // a little hacky

    // OR per @Lombax, move header to front
    UIView *sectionView = [self.tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];
    [self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:sectionView];
```

Comment: This sounds awesome and definitely worth a try. I am back at work on thursday and try it out first thing! To answer your question: No, that is most certainly not something I want to do Thnx

Comment: I just tried your code, and it does solve a part of the problem... as soon as I leave editing mode it's all good... but while still in editing mode and scrolling it overlaps.

Comment: Solved it by NOT setting the sectionHeaderView to front after sending the cell to the back. Just without the sending the cell back it works great. Thnx!

Answer (score 6):

It's a bug.
You can quickly solve it by adding, after the line:

```
[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:newPath];
```

this lines:

```
UIView *sectionView = [self.tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];
[self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:sectionView];
```

Comment: Is it possible to know why this answer has been downvoted? What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution but your code has number of issues. Who knows what happens if you fix them ;)

(1) Your cell may be nil after this line:

ListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

It should look like this:

```
ListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[ListCell alloc] initWithStyle:style
                                                    reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

(2) Two memory leaks in 
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

->>Fix (When you add the label as subview it gets +1 ref).

```
UILabel *textLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 21)] autorelease];
```

->>Fix (When you add the view as subview it gets +1 ref).

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[AXThemeManager sharedTheme].tableviewSectionHeaderBackgroundImage] autorelease];
```

(3) Not a defect but this may help you. Try using this instead of [table reloadData]. It allows to animate things nicely and is not such a hardcore way to update the table. I'm sure it is much more lightweight. Alternatively try to look for other "update" methods. Given you don't delete rows in your example, something like [updateRowsFrom:idxFrom to:idxTo] would help.

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Comment: 1. When UITableViewCells are defined in the storyboard, the check for nil does not seem to be required. I can't figure out why, but it is the case.

Comment: 2. If Paul is using ARC, then autorelease is neither required now allowed.

Comment: 3. I confirmed that reloadSections does work as well as reloadData. However I would say that UITableViewRowAnimationNone looks better than UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic.

Comment: ok, agreed with all you said. As for (1), not sure that story board thing will help in memory pressure case. Let's be on safe side.

Comment: There is no memory pressure case. As of iOS 5, the system will ensure you get a valid cell back as long as you register the nib in viewDidLoad. In iOS 6, you can register a class.

Comment: @Morgan already wrote what I was about the write. I haven't written the initial code, however I wondered the same when I read it and came to the same conclusion as Morgan and JMStone.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

  float  heightForHeader = 40.0;
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=heightForHeader&&scrollView.contentOffset.y>=0) {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>=heightForHeader) {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-heightForHeader, 0, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this problem was to set the zPosition of the view in the section header.

```
headerView.layer.zPosition = 1000 //just set a bigger number, it will show on top of all other cells.
```